# How to write dockerfile for front end web app

Tags: java, docker, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

Trying to deploy my first Java web app to Google Kubernetes. It must have 3 containers.

1 - front end web app

2 - back end Java web app- Jersey web service

3 - Postgres server

The whole web app is working on Eclipse Jee (Tomcat) on my laptop with no issue. The web app is very simple SPA with no Maven or Gradle build.
For backend: Dockerfile

```
FROM tomcat:9.0
ADD backend.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/backend.war
EXPOSE 8080
```

The image from the above is working fine. But for front end web app, I am really confused. Tried following variants without any success:
a)

```
FROM  tomcat:9.0
ADD frontend.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/frontend.war
```

b)

```
FROM tomcat:9.0
COPY frontend.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/frontend.war
EXPOSE 8080
```

c)

```
FROM 8.0-jre8-alpine
COPY frontend.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/frontend.war
```

When I tried to access my site using the loadbalancer IP which google provided on browser, getting Not reachable message.

Comment: Without knowing more about your application this is a bit tricky to answer.  Are you able to make a github repo for this so people can see the code (or a simple version of it). That being said you would definitely want an image for an application server capable of running the .war (tomcat, et.al) you also need to make sure you expose the ports. How are you running this? Are you running it in docker or are you immediately putting it on Google Kubernetes? I would try to run it in Docker for windows first. Then you have the issue of getting that to run in Kubernetes.

Comment: Then you have lots of things to check; Is the web.xml being coppied into the correct location? Has the routing been set up correctly? What do the logs (if any) say? It might be easier to find a working example that you can retrofit your app into

Comment: My front end is basically Java Dynamic Web Project which is created on Eclipse Jee. It is html+javascript+css+angluarjs+jquery. Actually no any Java code. Backend is a  pure Java web service based on Jersey. I created an image using the above Dockerfile for my back end project/war and tested successfully. But for the front end war, I have no idea how to create Dockerfile. I would like to deploy my front-end and back-end to separate pods.

Comment: At the moment, I am not really worried about backend and postgres pods/containers. I would like to test my front end first by accessing from browser.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my sample web application with backend as mysql database.

**Front-end Dockerfile**

```
FROM  tomcat:9.0
ADD art-gallery-management.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/art-gallery-management.war
WORKDIR /usr/local/tomcat/
CMD ["catalina.sh" "run"]
EXPOSE 8080/tcp
```

**Back-end Dockerfile**

```
FROM mysql:latest
WORKDIR /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
ADD Schema.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
CMD ["mysqld"]
EXPOSE 3306/tcp
```

**Starting containers**

```
docker container run -d --name art-gallery-management-db -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=vision -p 3306:3306 bukkasamudram/art-gallery-management:db-latest 
docker container run -d --name art-gallery-management-app --link art-gallery-management-db -p 8090:8080 bukkasamudram/art-gallery-management:app-latest
```

Make sure to use **link** option to link front-end container with back-end container.

Comment: For more information you can even refer my Docker hub repository.
https://hub.docker.com/u/bukkasamudram

Comment: So your backend image is only mysql. But how about your backend logic? Something like model logic? Did you bundle it to your front end with your htlms and javascripts? But should not we keep them separate to take advantage of containers? My understanding is that front-end, backend logic(web services), and DB  should be deployed to separate containers/pods.

Comment: If your question is about DDL/model of the database, then i updated my answer with ADD command to mysql image. Mysql executes all the .sh and .sql files present under entrypoint location in alphabetic order. So i created Schema.sql with all required ddl statements and placed in entrypoint.